# Get current pageindex of gridview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a gridview with paging enabled. Also I have few button click events outside gridview and now I want to capture the pageindex eachtime before proceeding with events.

**Code:**

```
protected void btnRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //capture current pageindex of gridview
       //then proceed with event flow
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Page Index Change Event of Gridview and store the Current Page Index for e:g

```
gridId.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
ViewState["currentpage"] = e.NewPageIndex;
```

You can get it on button click event as below:

```
int pageId=0;
pageId=Convert.toInt32(ViewState["currentpage"]);
```